# How to apply a coloured tint on the background on some rows in a striped table?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What needs to go in the `.add-background-tint`-class in order to add a semi transparent background colour on top of the table stripes? I want to keep the stripey-ness, and highlight certain rows.

CSS:

```
.highlighted-row {
    /* what goes here? */
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="highlighted-row"><td>row 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="highlighted-row"><td>row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so it is using odd/even setting colors now? Why not just change the color?

Comment: `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);` to the column instead of row:
Running sample here:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
  .highlighted-row td{
 background:rgba(200,0,0,0.1);
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="highlighted-row"><td>row 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="highlighted-row"><td>row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 4</td></tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't maintain the stripey-ness of the table. All highlighted rows will be the same colour.

Comment: @Stian You can't really apply two different background colors to the same element. In case of background images blend works but not for background colors alone. I have modified the solution to apply the transparent color to the `td` element. You get a similar result in a simpler approach than the current compliocated answer.

Comment: Yes, this is much better! :) Thanks!

Comment: Glad that you have found this helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Only way to really do that is to alter the code and add another element in the cell and take up the full width, but that will also mean you would have to do  stuff with the text to be above it. Does not really make sense. Just make another rule and change the color.

```js
document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
 e.target.closest("tr").classList.toggle('highlighted-row')
})
```

```css
tr{
  background-color: #AABBDD
}
tr.highlighted-row {
  background-color: #DDDD88;
}


tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #CCDDEE
}
tr.highlighted-row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FDFFAA;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="highlighted-row"><td>row 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="highlighted-row"><td>row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 4</td></tr>
</table>
```